What's the difference between *p++ and *p += 1 in C?
I have just started learning about pointers in C and was using a pointer p to iterate through the elements of an array.
My goal was to increment every element by one, but after applying the increment operator, I noticed a rather confusing output. Instead of showing value + 1, it would only show odd numbers within the array.
Here's the code:
#include <stdio.h>

#define N 10

int main(void)
{
    int a[N] = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}, *p;
    for (p = &a[0]; p < &a[N]; p++)
    {   
        *p++;
        printf("%d ", *p);
    }
    
    return 0;
}

output:
1 3 5 7 9

I then replaced ++ with += 1, and the output was as I was first expecting:
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10

I don't really understand what happened here, until now I thought both notations were equivalent for every use case.

*p++ increments p and fetches the value it pointed to before the increment. You don't do anything with the value though. Might want to print it: printf("%d (%d) ", *p, p[-1]); OTOH *p += 1; adds 1 to the value p points to.

*p++; ought to give a warning on a decent compiler. For example gcc -Wall.

@Lundin Using Visual Studio 2019, I get a warning of "Warning C6269 Possibly incorrect order of operations:  dereference ignored." with warning level 3 using /W3 compiler option.


What's the difference between *p++ and *p += 1 in C99?

It is a matter of operator precedence:

*p++:
++ has higher precedence over dereferencing *,
and so it is equivalent to: *(p++).
I.e. the pointer is incremented and then dereferenced.

*p += 1:
dereferencing * has higher precendnce over +=,
and so it is equivalent to: (*p) += 1.
I.e. the pointer is dereferenced, and then the result is incremented.


If you want to have the result of (2) (*p += 1) without using +=, you can achieve it by using parenthesis, i.e.: (*p)++.
Alternatively you can use pre-increment which does not even require parenthesis: ++*p.

@TedLyngmo good point - added.

... and ++*p ... :-)

@TedLyngmo you are right, but I prefer using parenthesis to be explicit and avoid having to "guess" the precedences ...

Well, you don't have guess precedence for ++*p, as the operators are on "one side". There's also the belief that pre-increment ++p might be faster than p++ (even if compilers generally optimize it), which makes pre-increment the preferred variant.

@HansOlsson I meant that I prefer to use parenthesis in general for explicitness. You are right in this specific case. Anyway - I added this option to my answer to complete it.

@HansOlsson I believe that belief the ++p is better than p++ may be relevant in C++ (iterators? custom objects?), not so much in C.

@pmg I think HansOlsson refers to the fact that theoretically p++ requires to keep a temporary with the previous value of p which is also relevant in C. However it's very common for compilers to optimize it and make ++p and p++ effectively the same. See here.

Hi @wohlstad, thank you a lot for your answer!! I'm happy to understand it now :)

@BrunoFernandes you're welcome, happy to help !

*p++ will evaluate as *(p++) which moves p to the next address and gets the value from there. You wanted (*p)++ instead, example:
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int a  = 5;
    int *p = &a;
    printf("Initialization: %d\n", *p);
    (*p)++;
    printf("Increment: %d", *p);
    return 0;
}

Whenever operator precedence does not help you, use parantheses to force the operator precedence you want.
